# Write all combinations of values to csv

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a csv file that contains the following format.  For the first column, ABC repeat 3 times and AAA1 also repeat 3 times. and then AAA1 increment by 1 become AAA2 and then increment by another 1 become AAA3. I want to repeat such increment by N times and then switch to BBB1 and repeat also N times.  The following is my code. I know they are wrong. please help me.

```
with open(file.csv, 'r') as input:
    reader = csv.reader(input,lineterminator='\n', delimiter = ',')

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    all.append(row)
    alist= ["AAA","BBB"]
    count=0
    for row in reader:
        count+=1
        row.insert(2, (random.choice(alist)+ (str(count)))) 
        all.append(row)

with open(file.csv, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n',delimiter = ',')
```

this is what I want to create

[image]

```
Block ID    Stage ID
A      AAA1                 
B      AAA1                         
C      AAA1                         
A      AAA2                         
B      AAA2                         
C      AAA2                         
A      BBB1                         
B      BBB1                         
C      BBB1                         
A      BBB2                         
B      BBB2                         
C      BBB2
```

Comment: First Column Second Third column
1 A AAA1
2 B AAA1
3 C AAA1
4 A AAA2
5 B AAA2
6 C AAA2
7 A BBB1
8 B BBB1
9 C BBB1

Comment: Your question contradicts itself, first you're saying you want to increment to AAA3 but the example is showing up to AAA2 then moves to BBBB1. Which one is it?

Comment: I am using portable python, so I cannot use panda. Thx

Comment: actually, I want to increment to N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
  number_of_times_to_repeat_stage_prefix = 4
  stage_prefixes = ["AAA","BBB"]
  block_ids = list('ABC')
  text = []
  for stage_prefix in stage_prefixes:
      block_counter = 0
      for i in range(number_of_times_to_repeat_stage_prefix):
          for block in block_ids:
              text.append([block, stage_prefix + str(block_counter+1)])
          block_counter+=1

  with open("E:/file.csv", 'w') as output:
      writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n',delimiter = ',')
      writer.writerows(text)
```

With the repeat set to 4 I get:

```
A   AAA1
B   AAA1
C   AAA1
A   AAA2
B   AAA2
C   AAA2
A   AAA3
B   AAA3
C   AAA3
A   AAA4
B   AAA4
C   AAA4
A   BBB1
B   BBB1
C   BBB1
A   BBB2
B   BBB2
C   BBB2
A   BBB3
B   BBB3
C   BBB3
A   BBB4
B   BBB4
C   BBB4
```

Comment: Thank you. that's exactly what I wanted it!

Answer (score 0):

You originally had an R tag, not sure if you're open to an R solution but here goes:

```
NN <- 2 #"repeat N times..."
DF <- data.frame("Block ID" = LETTERS[1:3],
                 "Stage ID" = paste0(rep(c("AAA", "BBB"), each = 3 * NN),
                                     rep(1:NN, each = 3)))
write.csv(DF, file = "file.csv")
```

Comment: I am using portable python, so I cannot use panda. Thx